# How can I highlight specific text in a richtextbox using C#?

Tags: c#

The title might not make sense so here's a more in-depth explanation:

I'm currently working on a UI Typing Test, where the user will be timed while they enter the sample text provided. At the end of the test, it needs to display the time elapsed, words per minute, and I need to "highlight the typing errors in red" where the text was entered.

For example, if the sample was:

"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." and the user entered:

"The quicc brown fox jumped over the lazy god." the end result would need to look like this :

"The quic**c** brown fox jumped over the lazy **g**o**d**." (Bold being substituted for highlighted in red)

How would I go about doing this? My searches haven't turned up the results I'm looking for.

Apparently I need to clarify that I am not asking you to write code for me. I'm asking for a nudge in the right direction, as I don't know how to go about extracting a specific part of the text from the box, highlight it and put it back.

Comment: Stack overflow is for users seeking help with a programming problem. Not to ask people to write code for you. What you need to do is show us what you have tried and where you have a specific problem. I suggest you review the tour before posting any more questions. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: My specific problem is that I don't know how to do it. I'm not saying "Hey, write this for me!" I'm saying "Hey, I need some help, can you point me in the right direction?"

Comment: Basically you need to create a TextRange object from the RichTextBox document that contains the text you want to highlight and then use the ApplyPropertyValue of the TextRange to set the property you want - in this case either the foreground or background to the color red.There maybe useful pointers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507240/textrange-and-richtextbox-in-c-sharp-wpf

Comment: Please review the tour, such questions are off-topic as being too broad. You need to ask a more specific question than "how do I do this?". The question you have asked here asks about multiple parts to a system. It is also off-topic to asks for guides/tutorials/etc. As I have said, please review the site tour before you continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know how to get the RTB.Text vs RTB.Rtf right?

Here is some [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) you might enjoy (or not).

Once you know the difference between those, you get the text, use that to build the rtf string, and then assign that string into the Rtf.

To modify the colors in your rtf string, you should check the documentation on how to format text with rtf.  [Here](http://www.pindari.com/rtf1.html) is the first google result I found.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you, your links got me thinking and something in the first about the SelectionColor property led me right to the solution I was looking for!